# SwiftUI How to put a TEXT in left top of it's superview?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I tried a lot of ways to make a view with one single text that show on the lefttop.

This is my code

```
struct ResponseView: View {
    
    var content: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(content)
                    .font(.system(size: 8))
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: what you mean? easier coding?

Comment: Yes. I don't think this is the right way to put a text on lefttop. I think in swiftUI this should be more less code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493788/how-to-position-views-relative-to-their-top-left-corner-in-swiftui

Answer (score 4):

I don't thing it can be simpler than below

```
ZStack {
    Text("Demo")
}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
```

and if you want to push it out of safe area top-left further just add `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` below `.frame` modifier

[image: demo]

Comment: I would not mind if I used VStack and Hstack for this kind of thing, Would you(@Asperi) mind to use ZStack? I mean I am okay with the VStack-HStack.