# SwiftUI. How to align root view to the left top corner?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI. I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text("Vasia")
            Text("Auuuuuuuuuuu")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

After compilation I get this:
[image]

I want these strings to be at the left top corner, not in the center. How to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Position Views Relative To Their Top Left Corner In SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493788/how-to-position-views-relative-to-their-top-left-corner-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is possible solution:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Vasia")
        Text("Auuuuuuuuuuu")
        Spacer()
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Spacer()` and wrap it inside HStack and VStack like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Vasia")
                Text("Auuuuuuuuuuu")
                
                Spacer()
            }

            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}
```